# Swift - Hide URL in lock screen / control center

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to hide URLs on the lock screen/control center that are playing in an UIWebView. This is an example of what I'm taking about:

[image]

How do I hide "http://livestreams.omroep.nl/..." this in swift3?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the information displayed at this place with the [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpnowplayinginfocenter):

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo =     
    [MPMediaItemPropertyArtist : "Artist",
     MPMediaItemPropertyTitle  : "Title"]
```

Comment: thank for ask but don't work ,i am a beginner in programming. what wrong my code :  https://www.mx7.com/view2/zUZQlOE7ba017Yjw